# Query Performance - Order By on Primary key or other key

Tags: sql, database, oracle11g, database-performance, query-performance

I have a question regarding the query performance for Oracle 11g.

I have two queries which order by primary key and non primary key.

materialid is a primary key.
material is a non primary key.

```
Query A: select * from rawmaterial_t order by materialid;
Query B: select * from rawmaterial_t order by material;
```

Which out of the above queries will be better in performance or will they be equivalent?
How can we improve the performance ?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you actually selecting every row from the table?  Or is there a `WHERE` clause in reality that is limiting the result to a smaller number of rows?  That will influence whether Oracle would consider any indexes or whether it would do a full table scan and then sort the result.  Is `rawmaterial_t` a heap-organized table?  Or is it an index-organized table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to check for performance is to try running the two queries on your own system.

In general, Oracle is smart enough to use an index if appropriate for `order by`, especially when there are no joins, aggregations, or filters.  If there are indexes on both columns, then the primary index is likely to be a wee bit faster.

So, I would expect `order by materialid` to be faster than `order by material`.  The performance should be comparable if you have an index on `material`.

Comment: If there is no `WHERE` clause, though, I'd expect that it would be more efficient to do a table scan and then sort the data in memory rather than using an index and doing a ROWID lookup for every row in the table.  As written, I wouldn't expect Oracle to use any indexes.

Comment: @JustinCave . . . Oracle may or may not use the index in this case.  The documentation does say "If an index can be used to satisfy an `ORDER BY` clause, then the optimizer uses this option and avoids a sort."  (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28274/optimops.htm#i52300)

Comment: Sure, it could.  I would just be very surprised if it did unless someone did a massive amount of playing around with the statistics on the table and the index in order to make the index look appealing enough to use.  I suspect, though, that the real problem involves some predicates that reduce the number of rows returned and make an index potentially much more reasonable.